# What is the MVVM Prism conversion of SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance?

Tags: c#, mvvm, containers, prism, mvvm-light

I'm fairly new to MVVM PPRISM, and I'm rewriting a project that uses MVVMLight SimpleIOC. I have the following lines of code in registering in MVVM Light and I have doubts whether this is the right way to convert it in MVVM Prims's DryIOC.

```
SimpleIoc.Default.Register< iClassA, ClassA >();
SimpleIoc.Default.Register< iClassB, ClassB >();
// The factory method is necessary to prevent the linker from removing the class A constructor
SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IClassC>(() => new ClassC(SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<IClassA>(), SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<IClassB>()));
```

My question is does `containerRegistry.GetContainer().Resolve<IClassInterface>()` the right way to convert from `SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance< IClassInterface >()`

```
containerRegistry.Register<iClassA, ClassA>();
containerRegistry.Register<iClassB, ClassB>();
containerRegistry.RegisterInstance<ClassC>(new ClassC((iClassA)containerRegistry.GetContainer().Resolve<iClassA>(), (iClassB)containerRegistry.GetContainer().Resolve<iClassB >()));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you seem to have two questions in one here, so I'll try to answer each part:

### Converting from SimpleIoc to IContainerRegistry

> I have the following lines of code in registering in MVVM Light and I have doubts whether this is the right way to convert it in MVVM Prims's DryIOC.

Prism's IContainerRegistry is an abstraction layer around the container meant to keep the vast majority of registration consistent regardless of which DI Container you are using with Prism. This also makes it easier to add support for different containers since Prism has outlined the interface we expect a Container to be able to support.

For instance where you have:

```cs
SimpleIoc.Default.Register<iClassA, ClassA>();
```

This would in theory map to an equivalent:

```cs
containerRegistry.Register<iClassA, ClassA>();
```

Because you're dealing with an abstraction layer it really doesn't matter if the backing container was DryIoc, Unity, or even a custom implementation with SimpleIoc.

Now in the event that there is some container specific API you need to access you can always call the `GetContainer()` extension to access the underlying container (assuming you're using DryIoc or Unity).

### Resolving Types:

So if your container has a method called Resolve that returns the type then yes you could go down to the container to call it but the better question is why would you?

> My question is does containerRegistry.GetContainer().Resolve() the right way to convert from SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance()

In the event that you're trying to resolve something from IContainerRegistry because you need to some crazy initialization. I would suggest using one of DryIoc's built in API's where you might have:

```cs
containerRegistry.Register<IFoo, Foo>();
containerRegistry.GetContainer().Register<IBar>(Reuse.Singleton, 
       Made.Of(() => new BarImplementation("requiredString", Arg.Of<IFoo>()));
```

You'll notice here that I've purposely ignored your Rp1210 example:

```cs
// The factory method is necessary to prevent the linker from removing the class A constructor
SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IClassC>(() => new Rp1210(SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<IClassA>(), SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<IClassB>()));
```

There are two reasons I've ignored this...

1. The comment tells me why they've done this.. the linker. Either turn off linking, or update your linker config to preserve the ctor for your IClassA implementation.
2. The entire point of using an IoC container is that it will automatically understand that it needs to inject services that are registered.

You'll notice that I'm only referencing that Container specific API because it had a primitive value that I needed to inject.